Understanding @Transactional Behavior in Nested Method Calls
I have a method annotated with @Transactional, and within this method, I call another method that is not annotated with @Transactional. I am trying to understand the transactional behavior in this scenario.
My questions are:

When methodA() is called, does methodB() execute within the same transaction initiated by methodA()?
If an exception occurs in methodB(), will it cause the transaction in methodA() to roll back?

Here's an example for illustration:
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Transactional
    public void methodA() {
        // some database operations
        methodB();
    }

    public void methodB() {
        // some other database operations
    }
}


You need to read about Transaction Propagation.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation

Yes.   Since you never use a transaction propagation, the default propagation is REQUIRED. This means the Spring checks if there is an
active transaction, and if nothing exists, it creates a new one.
This transaction also will be used in methodB.
Yes. if you throw Exception in methodB, it will be passed to methodA as well. Since you only have one transaction here, if there was previous DB operation in methodA(), it will be rollback.


When dealing with transactional behavior in Spring, it’s important to understand how transactions are managed across method calls. Here’s a detailed explanation based on your scenario:

Transaction Propagation
When methodA() is called, does methodB() execute within the same transaction initiated by methodA()?

Yes, methodB() executes within the same transaction initiated by methodA(). In Spring, if a method is annotated with @Transactional, the transaction is managed by a proxy. When methodA() is called, the proxy starts a transaction. Since methodB() is called from within methodA(), it executes within the context of the same transaction. The @Transactional annotation on methodA() ensures that the entire execution context, including calls to other methods within the same class, runs within the same transaction.
2. Exception Handling and Transaction Rollback
If an exception occurs in methodB(), will it cause the transaction in methodA() to roll back?
Yes, if an exception occurs in methodB() and it is not caught and handled within methodB(), it will propagate up to methodA(), causing the transaction to roll back. By default, Spring will roll back the transaction for any unchecked exceptions (subclasses of RuntimeException) or errors. Checked exceptions (subclasses of Exception excluding RuntimeException) do not trigger a rollback unless explicitly configured to do so.
Here's a summary of the behavior:
Unchecked Exception (RuntimeException or its subclass): The transaction will be rolled back.
Checked Exception (Exception but not RuntimeException): The transaction will not be rolled back unless specified.

Example with Exception Handling
Here's an example of how this works with exception handling:
java
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Transactional
    public void methodA() {
        try {
            // some database operations
            methodB();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception if needed
            // Optionally rethrow the exception to trigger rollback
            throw e; // This will cause the transaction to roll back
        }
    }

    public void methodB() {
        // some other database operations
        if (someCondition) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An error occurred"); // This will trigger rollback
        }
    }
}

In this example:
If someCondition in methodB() is true, methodB() will throw a RuntimeException.
Since RuntimeException is an unchecked exception, it will propagate up to methodA().
The transaction managed by methodA() will be marked for rollback due to the uncaught RuntimeException.

Important Notes
Transaction Management: Ensure your Spring configuration is correctly set up to enable transaction management, usually with @EnableTransactionManagement in a configuration class.
Proxy Limitation: Transactional behavior is managed by proxies in Spring. Direct internal calls (i.e., one method in the same class calling another method without going through the proxy) will not go through the transactional proxy. This is not an issue in your example as methodA() calls methodB() internally within the same transaction.

In summary, in your example, methodB() runs within the same transaction initiated by methodA(). If an exception occurs in methodB() and propagates up to methodA(), it will cause the transaction to roll back, provided the exception is an unchecked exception.

This answer looks like a copy-paste from ChatGPT. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy
